# Returning the highest int from a set, or list

Tags: java, int

I know I can use `Math.max(int, int)` to return the highest of TWO Integers, but lets say I have an SQL Table, containing Names, A rank/score of some sort(in the form of an integer), how can I take those scores, and get the highest of them?

Or, how can I sort them from highest to lowest, then I can take care of the rest?

Comment: Either or and.

Meaning, either one work, or both of them if possible :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a simple MySQL query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The first row in will be the highest.

Comment: Or you could do `SELECT max(score) FROM table_name`

Comment: Good call on doing this in the database, not the application.

Comment: You should then at least use `LIMIT 1`, so the SQL database can optimize this better.

Answer (score 2):

Well, sorting is more expensive than finding the maximum.

The probably most popular code to find the maximum is:

```
int max = data[0];
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    max = Math.max(max, data[i]);
}
```

There is nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Sorting will work, but sorting is in `O(n log n)`, while this obviously is only `O(n)`.

Comment: Dependent on the size of the dataset and the structure of the database. If there is index on the rank column (which maybe is not such a bad idea), then the retrieval of max result would take `O(log(n))` time. And even if there is no index, sorting it using highly-optimized database engine could for smaller amounts of data be quicker than passing the whole table to Java and searching there.

Comment: His question was so vague, it was not clear to me that he is only interested in database solutions. Of course, if you have a good database engine, you should use `max` or `order by, limit 1`. But then the question would have been trivial...